# Matrix Multiplication X'X

Tags: matrices

In my econometrics textbook, the author states this result.

[image]

He assumes only that **X** is an n x K matrix. He states **x<sub>i</sub>** is the i<sup>th</sup> column vector of matrix X. But that implies **x<sub>i</sub>** has dimensions n x 1, so **x<sub>i</sub>x<sub>i</sub>'** is an n x n matrix, so a sum of n x n matrices is also an n x n matrix. But **X'X** has dimensions K x K.

Can someone please explain what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Everything is correct. $X'$ is a $K\times n$ matrix so $X'X$ is a $K \times K$ matrix. The thing is that finding $X'X$ is essentially multiplying the corresponding columns of $X$ which we have $K$ of them with one another thus we have a $K\times K$ matrix as the product.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\mathbf x_i$ is a **column** vector of $\mathbf X$, we should have
$$\mathbf{X'X}=[\mathbf x_1, \cdots,\mathbf x_n]'[\mathbf x_1, \cdots,\mathbf x_n]=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf x_1'\\ \vdots \\ \mathbf x_n'\end{bmatrix}[\mathbf x_1, \cdots,\mathbf x_n]=(\mathbf x_i'\mathbf x_j)_{n\times n}$$
which is **not** the sum of $\mathbf x_i\mathbf x_i'$ which should be $\mathbf X\mathbf X'$ instead.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought! But he applies this identity over and over throughout the textbook, so I'm sure I must be wrong somewhere, I just don't know where...

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in a footnote in a different chapter of the textbook: **x<sub>j</sub>** is a column vector corresponding to the **j**<sup>th</sup> column of **X**, but **x<sub>i</sub>** is a column vector that is the transpose of the **i**<sup>th</sup> row vector of **X**. So, **x<sub>i</sub>'** is actually the **i**<sup>th</sup> row vector of **X**. Not sure why this is the case, but hope that clarifies it for anyone else reading this.